# Cannot use Export Release Build

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I've just moved to a new computer and imported all of my Flash Builder projects. When I try to Export a Release Build I get the following error message:

```
 Encountered errors or warnings while building project Test.mxml.
 Linked resources are not supported by this application.
```

I get the same message for a new project as well as for an old project. Restarting FB makes no difference. Can anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: check list 
1. Clean Your Project and Library
2. Clean its dependent Project
3. Build Once(Till now Solve issue) 
->once run the project and post result here of it....
->Which version of flash builder do you use ?????

Comment: I've decided to reinstall my operating system and start from scratch!

Comment: one another trick if not reinstalled your OS. please do it
-> make another new test project, put a single button or label in it then run the project. if it run properly then you have no mistake in your OS. you must try to find what's wrong in you FB...

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you really need to reinstall the OS! You might have to restart Flash Builder.. and that should clear any issues associated with cached objects etc.
Check and see if there is really something wrong with your project.. if you don't seem to find anything, create a new project - just an empty one with a button on the canvas and then try exporting a release build.